# Cant see static methods in compiled classes in same package

Tags: java, scope, compilation, static

I want to define a class with static flags for debug modes that objects throughout my program can see and output debug information accordingly. The "Option" class has no dependencies and I compile it first. (all from commandline / .bat file) The Option class compiles, but classes which reference it won't compile with a "cannot find symbol" error.

```
//Options - holds options for code, including debug modes, getters, setters
package UserViewer;

public class Option {

    private static boolean debug1 = false;
    private static boolean debug2 = false;
    private static boolean debug3 = false;
    private static boolean debug4 = false;

    public static boolean isDebug1() {
        return debug1;
    }
    public static void setDebug1(boolean val) {
        debug1 = val;
    }
    public static boolean isDebug2() {
        return debug2;
    }
    public static void setDebug2(boolean val) {
        debug2 = val;
    }
    public static boolean isDebug3() {
        return debug3;
    }
    public static void setDebug3(boolean val) {
        debug3 = val;
    }
    public static boolean isDebug4() {
        return debug4;
    }
    public static void setDebug4(boolean val) {
        debug4 = val;
    }
}
```

Here is the first class I attempt to compile that references the static methods in Option

```
//contains all the User Interface elements
package UserViewer;

import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

class UIPane extends BorderPane implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    UIPane() {
        if(Option.isDebug1() == true) { System.out.println("UIPane succesfully loaded."); }
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        if(Option.isDebug2() == true) { System.out.println("Action Event detected in UIPane."); }
    }
}
```

Here is compile.bat

```
javac -d . CONST.java
javac -d . Option.java
javac -d . UIPane.java
javac -d . App.java
javac -d . UserViewer.java
java UserViewer.UserViewer DEBUG1
pause
```

Since they are all in the same package - UserViewer - I thought I could reference these static methods from anywhere in the program.

Here's the (first) compiler error:

```
C:\...\UserViewer>javac -d . UIPane.java
UIPane.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    if(Option.isDebug1() == true) { System.out.println("UIPane succesfully loaded."); }
 symbol:   variable Option
 location: class UIPane
UIPane.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    if(Option.isDebug2() == true) { System.out.println("Action Event detected in UIPane."); }
 symbol: variable Option
 location: class UIPane
```

I have the same problem with CONST.java and with all other objects that depend on CONST and Option, but I have omitted the other errors since they all seem to be the same problem - the rest of my code cannot see Option.class or CONST.class, though they are in the same package. Option.class and CONST.class do compile and are in the correct package subdirectory UserViewer.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT: Solution in the comments**

I needed to either compile all the classes simultaneously or declare classpaths for dependent classes.

My new .bat file looks like this:

```
javac -d . *.java
java -cp ./UserViewer;. UserViewer.UserViewer DEBUG1
```

Comment: why are you compiling one class at a time? why not compile all classes in one statement like `javac *.java`

Comment: You need to compile them all in one go, or at least make the previously-compiled classes available to the compiler on the classpath.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen - I believe both solutions would work. I used Prateek Jain's solution, compiling all the classes at once with javac *.java.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you have to compile the classes all in one go.

These are the steps to do that:

1. Navigate to the directory of your main class with `cd` in the console.
2. Type `javac NameOfYourMainClass.java` and hit enter.

An example:

Imagine this is your file system:

- desktop

  - myProject

    - main

      - MainClass.java <-- The class that contains `main(String[] args)`
    - debug

      - Option.java

Now assuming the `myProject` folder is the root of your project, you would use the console to change the working directory to `main` and then write `javac MainClass.java`.

If you want to run you your program afterwards, type `java NameOfYourMainClass`.

Comment: My main class is dependent on the objects it instantiates, so it won't compile unless the other classes are compiled... maybe I'm misunderstanding your solution.

Prateek Jains solution worked: javac *.java to compile all classes at once. I'm sure the -cp solution Andy Turner suggested would work also.

Comment: This is the solution you said you used in the comments below the question.

Comment: I don't believe it is. `javac NameOfYourMainClass.java` attempts to compile `NameOfYourMainClass` without any of the other classes on which it is dependent. Attempting to do that predictably produces dependency errors. The solution was to compile all classes simultaneously, not just the main class which has the dependencies. The solution was to compile all classes in my folder with `javac *.java`. Also, I needed to add the -d to compile to a package folder so the solution was `javac -d .*java` not `javac mainClass.java`

Comment: This just worked for me when I was testing, but you probably have a very specific setup, so I'll accept my defeat. ;)